# How to remove a particular html tag and its content which is inside a div, using div id by jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following div tag, which will be created onload by jquery. I want to remove only  the span tag and its contents which is being created inside the div. How can i do this using jquery ? I have tried innerHTML but it deletes all the contents of the div with id uniform-qualification, as I want to delete only the span tag below.

```
<div id="uniform-qualification" class="">
<span>BCh</span>
 </div>
```

Note : the span tag cannot be given with an id as its being created dynamically from the UI plugin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("#uniform-qualification > span").remove();
```

but you'll need to provide more information if you want a more informed answer. For example, if you have more than one span but only want to remove the first one you'll need something like:

```
$("#uniform-qualification > span:eq(0)").remove();
```

Answer (score 2):

To remove all span elements within the div try the following:

```
$('#uniform-qualification span').remove();
```

To remove only child span elements:

```
$('#uniform-qualification > span').remove();
```

To remove only the first child span element:

```
$('#uniform-qualification > span').first().remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#uniform-qualification').html('');
```

That'll do the trick.